# Hubspot Custom Workflow Actions are not listing in Workflow tool

Tags: crm, hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-api

I have followed the below steps to create a custom workflow action:

1. Created a Hubspot developer account and created an App with proper scope, redirect URL and etc.. in it.
2. I was able to create the action definitions through post man using this App id and H API key.
3. The definitions were also listed when I use the GET Call
   https://api.hubspot.com/automation/v4/actions/121**?hapikey=5af26**-***-***-***-*********
4. I wanted to use this action in my workflow tool in my test account and sandbox account. So installed it using the install URL in the App section.
5. Chose the App, accepted permission and received the code also generated the access token with it, during the installation process. (oath process done)
6. The App was showing up in the "Connected Apps" section in the Integration tab.
7. So in order to test my App I went to worflowtool but I couldn't find the actions which I custom-defined to appear here.  Can someone help me, what I'm missing here...
   Is there some other way I can view the UI of the defined action definition?? Why the custom action is not serachable or not listed in the workflow?

[image]

PS: Though the name is Twilio, I'm not integrating it with Twilio, I know there is integration plugins existing already.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Could be a few possible things that I personally encountered:

1. `published` field in your action is set to false. By default the action is created in this way. You need to pass `published: true` in the creation POST request for it to be enabled on creation. Alternatively you could make a PATCH request and update it after creation.
2. `objectTypes` field in your action isn't correct. I has created my action with `objectTypes: ['DEALS']` but was checking for the action in a Contact workflow.